# Can I use beforeSend() to get info about widget openers?

Tags: javascript, usersnap

I am reading the documentation [here](http://usersnap.com/support/docs/javascript) for custom methods I can use, but I am not able to get the information on how many users opened the widget, but didn't use it to send me a feedback.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var _usersnapconfig = {
         beforeSend: function(obj) {
            obj.addInfo = 'Some User Information';
         }
     };
   </script>
```

Can I use *beforeSend* to count those users/events somehow and the to compare with the feedback I am receiving in GitHub Issues?